# Can't call method "dclone" on unblessed reference

Tags: perl

I am getting the following error.

```
"Can't call method "dclone" on unblessed reference"
```

What is meant by "**unblessed reference**" and how to correct the same. Please refer the below code.
**Code**

```
use strict;                                                                        
use warnings;                                                                      
use YAML::XS 'LoadFile';                                                           
use Data::Dumper;                                                                  

my $config = LoadFile('config.yml');                                               
my $record1 = $config->{Record1};                                                  
print "record1: $record1\n";                                                       
print Dumper($config);                                                             

$config->{Record2} =  dclone $config->{Record1};                                   
print Dumper($config);
```

**Following is the output**

```
record1: ARRAY(0x275fa88)
$VAR1 = {
          'Record1' => [
                         {
                           'Name' => 'Karun'
                         },
                         {
                           'Phone' => 123
                         }
                       ]
        };
Can't call method "dclone" on unblessed reference at p1.pl line 11.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dclone` is not a core function in Perl nor is it provided by the modules you've imported. It is provided by [Storable](https://metacpan.org/pod/Storable) though. You are likely missing

```
use Storable 'dclone';
```

Comment: without knowing that dclone is a function, perl parses the code as an indirect object call of a method dclone on a class or object `$config->{Record1}`, as if it were `$config->{Record1}->dclone`.  with parens added (`dclone($config->{Record1})`), it instead will give a more helpful "Undefined subroutine &main::dclone called" error.